# Validate if username already exists

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, select, sql-insert

In the form that I create new users, I would like it to validate if the username already existed or not, then in the register button I put the following code:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim Inserir As String = "INSERT INTO `techstorehunter`.`utilizadores`(`Username`,`Password`,`pergunta`,'resperg')VALUES('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & ComboBox1.Text & "')"
        ExecuteQuery(Inserir)

    Catch
        MessageBox.Show("Username already exists")
    End Try

    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Insert a username")
    End If
    If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Insert a password")
    End If
    If TextBox3.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("You need to answer a question")
    End If
    If ComboBox1.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("You need to select a question")
    End If
End Sub
```

But everytime I create a user it says that it already exists, even if not, what i can do? Thanks.

PS : "Inserir" means "Insert" but my language is Portuguese.

Comment: Why would you catch any and all exceptions and tell the user that the specified user name already exists when you have no idea whether that's the case or not?  A duplicate record is just one of many reasons an exception could be thrown there and, if it's always happening, it's almost certainly for a different reason.  If you want to catch the specific exception that is thrown when a duplicate user name is inserted then do that and treat other exceptions differently.  Start by actually looking at the exception that is thrown.

Comment: Also, why are you doing the rest of your validation after the insert?  How is it logical to do something first and then check whether you can do it?  Would you take a step into the street first and then check whether there is traffic coming?

Comment: Finally, you should learn how to use parameters with your queries.  The fact that you're not could be the reason for the unexpected exception in the first place but, even if it's not, it's still VERY bad practice.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Why don’t you provide the OP with an example of parameterisation? That would be more in keeping with the spirit of this site, rather than simply leaving a snarky comment. Clearly the OP needs help.

Comment: I'm not good in programming, but i want to learn and finish school, even if im not good, i want to learn.

Comment: Thanks @twoleggedhorse

Comment: @twoleggedhorse, because the question was not about parameterisation and it's easy to find information on the subject. I've been posting on sites like this for about 15 years and if I spent time teaching everyone who posts code like this how to use parameters then I'd have no time for anything else. Where's your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code :

First, you validate the input *after* running the sql query : you should validate first, and if everything goes well then do the INSERT, otherwise you are exposing to either inserting dumb data to database, or getting the « User already exists » warning on incomplete input

Also, you catch all database errors and interpret them as « User already exists » ; by proceeding this way you are potentially hiding other database errors than duplicate user record. The proper way to proceed is to :

- after form validation, check for per-existing user with a query like follows, where the question mark should be replaced by the submitted user name. If the query returns anything, then you know that you have a duplicated user for sure, and you can raise the appropriate warning and stop the processing.

```
SELECT 1 FROM `techstorehunter`.`utilizadores` WHERE `Username` = ?
```

- if the first query returns nothing, you can run the INSERT statement
- everytime your run a query, you want to catch errors, report them with the full error message, and abort the processing